# Akeneo Install Error - Install the Ghostscript executable at least 9.27 version

Tags: ghostscript, akeneo

I want to install Akeneo with:

```
php7-73STABLE-CLI -c /kunden/xxxxx/webseiten/web/akeneo/pim-community-standard/D3066475_php7.ini bin/console pim:install --force --symlink --clean --env=dev
```

But i get the following error:

```
Install the Ghostscript executable at least 9.27 version
```

The problem is: Ghostscript is installed and active! A 'gs -v' gets

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.27 (2019-04-04) Copyright (C) 2018 Artifex Software, Inc.  All rights reserved.
```

Can anybody help me?
Best wishes!

Comment: What is the OS ? If its Windows, have you installed the 32 or 64-bit version ? WHich one does akeneo need ?

Answer (score 0):

This error comes from a bug in last version of Akeneo (4.0). A fix has been submitted on our repository for master [here](https://github.com/akeneo/pim-community-dev/pull/11550).

You can apply it to your project if you don't want to wait :)

Comment: How? How can I apply this solution? I using command composer create-project akeneo/pim-community-standard /home/user/Akeneo "5.0.*@stable"